# Plotting X against (Y,Z)

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Given a data or dataframe with features say X, Y and Z

```
 X    Y    Z
 4    3    2
 5    6    9
 1    2    10
```

I would like to draw a plot of X against Y and Z something like that (plot(X,(Y,Z))) intuitively.
Initially I thought it was 3D, but unfortunately its not.

So please I would like to know if there is a way to do it in python. I checked out scipy.interpolate.griddata and I don't know if that is what I am looking for.

Comment: Scatterplot Y against X and Z against X?

Comment: Uhmm i don't know if that's what I am looking for, but I will try it and see.  Thanks. I was thinking more like X against both Y and Z. sounds like a 2D

Comment: If a dataframe, `df.plot(x='X', y=['Y', 'Z'])`.

Comment: I did that in a scatter and I gave me a KeyError.

Comment: `ax = df.plot(x='X', figsize=(10, 5))` or `ax = df.plot(x='X', ls='', marker='.', figsize=(10, 5))` is all that's required

Comment: The correct way to use pandas to plot `Y` on the left y-axis and `Z` on the right y-axis is with `ax = df.plot(x='X', secondary_y=['Z'])` or `ax = df.plot(x='X', ls='', marker='.', secondary_y=['Z'])`, but I don't think this is what you're asking for.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in comments, you can pass the two columns as parameter for `y`:

```
df.plot(x='X', y=['Y', 'Z'])
```

Output:
[image]

Another option, is to manually twin the axes to add another axis:

```
ax = df.plot(x='X', y='Y')
df.plot(x='X', y='Z', color='r', ax=ax.twiny())
```

Output:
[image]